# How to create and populate generic Dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

How to create and populate generic `Dictionary<>` it should be populated by this types
`TKey= string, TValue=Point`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
Dictionary<string, Point> spdic = new Dictionary<string, Point>();

spdic.Add("mystring", new Point(0,0)); 
spdic.Add("mystring1", new Point(23,30));
```

Answer (score 3):

How about something like

```
Dictionary<string, Point> dict = new Dictionary<string, Point>()
{    
    { "string A", new Point(0, 0) }
}
```

*Just to be different from the other answers and use an object initializer*

Comment: new new Point(0, 0)  - typo need to change

Answer (score 2):

Just like this

```
Dictionary<string,Point> dic = newDictionary<string,Point> ();
dic.Add("key", new Point(1,1));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Dictionary<string, Point> myDict = new Dictionary<string, Point>();
myDict.add(myString, myPoint);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
Dictionary<string, Point> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Point>();
myDictionary.Add("Some String", new Point(x, y));
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

```
Dictionary<String, Point> dict = new Dictionary<String, Point>();

dict.Add("abcd", new Point(65,99));
```

Here is the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

**EDIT** Please make sure you read the documentation or do some search because it is highly likely that you will find an answer to this type of question. Here is how you use the [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k.aspx) method

Answer (score 2):

You could also take a list of whatever type had your strings and Points in them and use

listOfThingsWithStringsAndPoints.ToDictionary(x => x.yourString, x=> x.yourPoint);

*Just to be different from the other answers and use ToDictionary*